# Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'ScheduerBinding' which excludes null

Tags: flutter, dart

I stared facing this issue after Flutter upgrade. 3.0.1

The app works but there are error/s (warning/s) in the terminal).

It seems like a Binding issue.

the error(warning) says: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'ScheduerBinding' which excludes null.

```
/C:/Software%20Utilities/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selectable.dart:459:24: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.

- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('/C:/Software%20Utilities/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').

      SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {

                       ^

/C:/Software%20Utilities/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/web_selection_manager.dart:119:24: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.

- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('/C:/Software%20Utilities/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').

      SchedulerBinding.instance!

                       ^

/C:/Software%20Utilities/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/overlay_manager.dart:138:28: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.

- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('/C:/Software%20Utilities/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').

      if (SchedulerBinding.instance!.schedulerPhase ==

                           ^

/C:/Software%20Utilities/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/overlay_manager.dart:140:26: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.

- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('/C:/Software%20Utilities/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').

        SchedulerBinding.instance!

                         ^

/C:/Software%20Utilities/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/overlay.dart:141:26: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.

- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('/C:/Software%20Utilities/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').

    if (SchedulerBinding.instance!.schedulerPhase ==

                         ^

/C:/Software%20Utilities/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/overlay.dart:143:24: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.

- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('/C:/Software%20Utilities/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').

      SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback(_markNeedsBuild);

                       ^

/C:/Software%20Utilities/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/overlay.dart:193:26: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.

- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('/C:/Software%20Utilities/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').

    if (SchedulerBinding.instance!.schedulerPhase ==

                         ^

/C:/Software%20Utilities/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_math_fork-0.5.0/lib/src/widgets/selection/overlay.dart:195:24: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.

- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('/C:/Software%20Utilities/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').

      SchedulerBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback(_markNeedsBuild);

                       ^
```

Ran flutter doctor found no issues...

here is Flutter Doctor output:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.675], locale en-IN)

    • Flutter version 3.0.1 at C:\Software Utilities\flutter

    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git

    • Framework revision fb57da5f94 (8 days ago), 2022-05-19 15:50:29 -0700

    • Engine revision caaafc5604

    • Dart version 2.17.1

    • DevTools version 2.12.2

 

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)

    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Vinay H P\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.0.0

    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\bin\java

    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840)

    • All Android licenses accepted.

 

[√] Chrome - develop for the web

    • CHROME_EXECUTABLE = C:\Program Files\BraveSoftware\Brave-Browser\Application\brave.exe

 

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.0.4)

    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community

    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.0.32014.148

    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

 

[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)

    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio

    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:

       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter

    • Dart plugin can be installed from:

       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-b60-7590822)

 

[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)

    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1

    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:

       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter

    • Dart plugin can be installed from:

       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840)

 

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2022.1)

    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1

    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:

       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter

    • Dart plugin version 221.5480

 

[√] Connected device (4 available)

    • Redmi Note 3 (mobile) • 754f4dd • android-arm64  • Android 6.0.1 (API 23)

    • Windows (desktop)     • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.675]

    • Chrome (web)          • chrome  • web-javascript • unknown

    • Edge (web)            • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 101.0.1210.53

 

[√] HTTP Host Availability

    • All required HTTP hosts are available

 

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 3):

This error comes after upgrading to flutter 3 

I got that error because of `getx`, so I update getx plugin version and everything working fine.

Comment: I am not using getx but pub upgrade didn't work.

Comment: Error was from flutter_html package. I think we need to wait till the packages are updated...

Answer (score 0):

you can try flutter html version ^3.0.0-alpha.3 (fixed the problems. :D Thanks)

Comment: But that's an alpha release of a now-released version. I assume it carries with it _other_ bugs. It may be worth highlighting those (e.g., by linking to a known issues page).